# Create fft2 result from rfft2 array

Tags: numpy, fft

I am trying to recreate the result of a full fft2 by manipulating the result of an rfft2. The documentation states that rfft2 only computes the positive coefficients since the negative coefficients have a symmetry with the positive ones when the input is real. This would be extremely useful for large arrays since computing the rfft2 is much faster than the full fft2.

So the below code is me trying to recreate the fft2 from the rfft2 output. I have tried all kinds of manipulations of the "left" array and can't quite get "same" to be true everywhere. Any ideas?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from skimage.data import camera

frame = camera()

full_fft = np.fft.fft2(frame)
real_fft = np.fft.rfft2(frame)

left = real_fft[:, :-1].copy()
right = np.flipud(left[:, ::-1])

sim_fft2 = np.hstack((left, right))

same = np.isclose(full_fft, sim_fft2)

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(same)

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(np.log(np.abs(full_fft)))

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(np.log(np.abs(sim_fft2)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the symmetry by doing the fft2 on a 6x6 array which then just required programming up a function to convert the output of a rfft2 to be the same as a fft2. Below is that function and an image of the symmetry.

```
def _rfft2_to_fft2(im_shape, rfft):
    fcols = im_shape[-1]
    fft_cols = rfft.shape[-1]

    result = numpy.zeros(im_shape, dtype=rfft.dtype)

    result[:, :fft_cols] = rfft

    top = rfft[0, 1:]

    if fcols%2 == 0:
        result[0, fft_cols-1:] = top[::-1].conj()
        mid = rfft[1:, 1:]
        mid = numpy.hstack((mid, mid[::-1, ::-1][:, 1:].conj()))
    else:
        result[0, fft_cols:] = top[::-1].conj()
        mid = rfft[1:, 1:]
        mid = numpy.hstack((mid, mid[::-1, ::-1].conj()))

    result[1:, 1:] = mid

    return result
```

[image: fft2 symmetry]